What are the Vedic antecedents for Caturvyūhavāda ('doctrine of four emanations') of Pāñcarātra theology?
In Pāñcarātra Bhagavatism, the four earthly emanations, or "Vyūhas", are identified as Saṃkarṣaṇa (Balarāma-Saṃkarṣaṇa, son of Vasudeva by Devakī), Vāsudeva Kṛṣṇa (son of Vasudeva by Devakī), Pradyumna (son of Vāsudeva Kṛṣṇa by Rukmiṇī), and Aniruddha (son of Pradyumna). The first of these emanations is the hero-god Vāsudeva, with the other emanations being his Vṛṣṇi kinsmen presented as extensions of Vāsudeva himself.
